Firefox not obeying system wide preferences

Ubuntu 22.04
Firefox 119

I have the /etc/firefox/syspref.js file below but my Firefox is not using the custom proxy settings and just defaulting to "Use system proxy configuration".
pref("browser.startup.page", 0);
pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
pref("network.proxy.http", "ip");
pref("network.proxy.http_port", port);
pref("network.proxy.ssl", "ip");
pref("network.proxy.ssl_port", port);
pref("network.proxy.ftp", "ip");
pref("network.proxy.ftp_port", port);
pref("network.proxy.gopher", "ip");
pref("network.proxy.gopher_port", port);
pref("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", true);


In Firefox, Connection Settings, first set Firefox to use proxy settings. Change Use system proxy settings to Manual proxy configuration.

It likely would be easier to perform the full Firefox configuration in that dialog, then capture those settings in changed files, if you need to copy that behavior to another profile.

so the /etc/firefox/syspref.js (which holds the proxy settings) seems to be deprecated. We need to use /usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/local-settings.js instead
